# Performance hit when using XmlReaderSettings.Schemas and specifying multiple schemas to be used

Tags: c#, xml, performance, xsd, xml-serialization

I am using `XmlReader` to validate a XML file as per the supplied schema.

For that I am creating an instance of `XmlReaderSettings` and setting it's `ValidationType` as `ValidationType.Schema` and it's `Schemas` Property as XxmlSchemaSet. A draft code is like

```
XmlReaderSettings rSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemaSet.Add(null, xsdPath1);
schemaSet.Add(null, xsdPath2);
schemaSet.Add(null, xsdPath3);
rSettings.Schemas.Add(schemaSet);

rSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

XmlReader validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(sr, rSettings);
```

sr is a `StreamReader`

This is actually legacy code and still has many problems which I have to fix. I know that `schemaSet.Add(null, xsdPath2)` looks nasty and ugly which I am going to fix.

What I want to ask is that since I have provided three xsd files, what performance hits should I expect? The xsd's are given in decreasing order of priority. All these XML schema are versioned, so I have added all of them so as to have a fallback mechanism.

What I am thinking was that JIT compiler will compiler only xsd1 try to parse the XML file with it and if it fails moves to next. I don't want all of the three xsd to be in memory.

This is where I am confused. What performance hit can I expect in specifying multiple schema files?

I am expected to improve the legacy codebase, so performance is always on the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing the schemas don't change much, you could consider loading/compiling your schemas and adding them to a cache as schemaset.

This would prevent reloading/recompiling of the schema's for each time you want to load a document that needs to be validated.

Hope this helps,